# Independent .NET Core MVC and ReactJS web application with same session

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core

I've an existing web application developed in ASP .NET Core MVC with EntityFramework. I would like to use ReactJs in the application for new page development.

Without making any changes in the existing project for ReactJs, I've a thought to create separate project for ReactJS in the same solution. Using sessions / token based authentication, we can access the ReactJs application. Internally, the ReactJS component(page) will be called from existing MVC application through route.

Could you please share your suggestions/bottlenecks on my approach.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "access the ReactJs application" and "ReactJS component(page) will be called from existing MVC application through route"? Isn't it the other way around? React is "just" a JS framework for building a user interface.
Please expand your question to describe more specifically what you're trying to achieve, what you have tried/considered and why you are e.g. looking at React. This will make it easier to understand what you're looking for.